# Problems with connection pool using Simple Data

Tags: c#, mysql, oracle11g, database-connection, simple.data

I'm facing a very difficult problem with a web a application that I'am implementing with a group of developers. We are using Simple Data to connect to a Oracle database but after several connection or when we have a lot of users the connection pool gets full and the application doesn't work any more. The problem is that Simple Data opens the connection to make the transactions but it never close the connection so the application stops the transactions, we saw at the simple data documentation that it says that althought in code it's not necessary to close the connection the simple data do it itself but is not true.

We already try to change the number of available connection from 100 to 50 per user, but the problem continues, another solution that we implemented was to open a share connection, but it didn't work either. The question is, Is there a way in code to Close the connections in the simple data?.

```
var db=Database.Open();
return db.Table.FindById(Id:2);
```

In that sample code, you can see that I open the connection, but there is no method to close it. If someone can help me with this problem I'll be grateful. Thank you.

Info:

We are using, NancyFx framework, C# an Oracle11g database.

Answer (score 0):

Old post but if anyone wondering about it! ...

As the docs on page (http://simplefx.org/simpledata/docs/pages/Start/OpeningAConnection.html) saya at the last line

> Simple.Data is quite aggressive in closing connections and holds no open connections to a data store by default, so you can keep the Database object returned from the Open*() methods hanging around without worrying.